# What are some large .NET projects with source code?

Tags: .net

I'd like to find a few large .NET projects that have public source code available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For winforms development, [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/).

Comment: Thanks, I that looks like it is more than big enough for my profiling purposes.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework.

Comment: Where is the source for that?

Comment: You can use Reflector to view the source; or you can download it from microsoft.

Comment: I just found a link with talks about it.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Paint.net](http://getpaint.net).

(Having said that, I now can't find the source download location :}

Comment: The author of Paint.NET decided to go closed-source some time ago, and as such the source code is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeplex.com/ - take your pick

Answer (score 2):

Since dependency injection is a hot subject at the moment check out [the castle project](http://castleproject.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is fairly large.

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) is one of the biggest projects around and worth studying if this is the purpose of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The SSCLI is has quite a lot of C# code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Data & Object Factory has a sample application that they publish (*Patterns in Action*) to showcase design patterns in .NET. The application shows implemetation of the design patterns from the Gang of Four and .NET versions of the patterns from *Head First Design Patterns*. It's all done in C#, and shows UIs done in ASP.NET, WPF, and WinForms. I don't regret the subscription one bit (and it wasn't much at all).

If you don't mind spending a few bucks for something that gives you lots of really useful, heavily documented, working code that models a real-world application (a shopping cart for an online store), it's worth it (at least, in my opinion).

I heartily recommend them.

[Data & Object Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[NeuronDotNet](http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/), an implementation of several types of artificial neural networks.